# How do I build all projects in a sub-project in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I've got a multi-build project which is organised like this:-

```
-root
  -project1
  -project2
  -project3
   --subproject1
   --subproject2
```

When I call the following:-

```
gradle project3:build
```

I only get a single empty jar named project3.jar, how would I instead instruct gradle to build every single sub-project of project3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
gradle -p project3 build
```

This will build `project3` and all its sub-projects.

The `-p` switch is used to specify the project directory.
More information [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:selecting_build).